# word2vec gives strange results on small example

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, word2vec, word-embeddings

I'm playing around with word2vec and just as a test, I put together a very small example, with five groups of words which appear together:

```
[["0", "1", "2", "3"], ["4000", "4001", "4002", "4003"], ["8000", "8001", "8002", "8003"], ["12000", "12001", "12002", "12003"], ["16000", "16001", "16002", "16003"]]
```

Here is the corpus:

```
0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 4000 4001 4002 4003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 8000 8001 8002 8003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 12000 12001 12002 12003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003 16000 16001 16002 16003
```

Then, I asked word2vec to embed each word in 2 dimensions. Here is the result:

[image: word2vec result]

I expected to see the five groups. Instead, it seems quite random.

I used the [original code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/)
with the following parameters:

```
./word2vec -train test.txt -output positions.txt -cbow 0 -size 2 -window 3 -negative 4  -binary 0 -iter 15
```

I played around with the parameters with no luck. Am I doing something wrong? Is the corpus too small? I did try with a lot more words but it didn't help much either.

Comment: Well, it actually turns out that with a much larger corpus, I do see the groups. The groups emerge with  50,000+ number of words (there were only 400 words in the example above). I guess this answers my question, but any comment is appreciated.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question and accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more experiments, I found out that the corpus was not big enough.
The groups emerge with 50,000+ number of words (there were only 400 words in the example above).
So, this seems to solve the problem, although I'm pretty sure that 400 words were enough to make the pattern significant.